# Disabling Azure Functions Queue trigger logging

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function v4 (C#) with a Queue Trigger attached which is spamming my logs in Application Insights (level trace). The logs has the following properties. Message:

```
Request [b84f2987-e464-4484-8144-a0b99c6b921f] PUT <BLOB STORAGE URL>/host?comp=lease x-ms-lease-action:renew x-ms-lease-id:f163ec32-443e-3ff0-ba7e-f1aafd1b9a97 x-ms-version:2021-08-06 Accept:application/xml x-ms-client-request-id:b84f2987-e464-4484-8144-a0b99c6b921f x-ms-return-client-request-id:true User-Agent:azsdk-net-Storage.Blobs/12.13.0,(.NET 6.0.19; Microsoft Windows 10.0.14393) x-ms-date:Sat, 05 Aug 2023 12:05:27 GMT Authorization:REDACTED client assembly: Azure.Storage.Blobs
```

Category: `Azure.Core` . LogLevel: `Information` .
I tried editing `hosts.json` in several ways, at the moment it looks like this, and the issue is still not solved

```json
"logLevel": {
      "default": "Warning",
      "System": "Warning",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Host.Results": "Information",
      "Function": "Information",
      "Host.Aggregator": "Warning",
      "Worker": "Warning",
      "Azure.Core": "Warning",
      "Azure.Storage.Queues": "Warning"
    }
```

Any hint on the changes required to increase the logging threshold for this assembly?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this in your host.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi yes that is there already unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information",
      "Azure.Core": "Warning",
      ...
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

`host.json` reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#logging

Comment: Hi, that's precisely what I have above there

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there are quite a few issues on github that have been solved in the last few years, though I've had a lot of similar issues and it's not immediately clear how to setup the host.json properly.

I noticed that the trace of the issue had the logLevel set to Warning in some of the custom dimensions, upping the Default LogLevel to Error made the issue disappear for me, you could potentially just do this for the `Azure.Core` assembly and also see if this makes a difference as I appreciate setting the default might not be ideal!

As well as this you might try adding `"enabledLiveMetricFilters": true` to the applicationInsights section. This is included in the [v4 migration host.json docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/migrate-version-1-version-4?tabs=net6-in-proc%2Cazure-cli%2Cwindows&pivots=programming-language-csharp#hostjson-file) and is meant to stop traces filling up the log stream but I've experienced that this also helps clean out application insights.

```
"logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Error"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
        "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
    }
}
```